# Why a string which contains '\0' and '\t' can't use operator == to compare with "\0\t"?

Tags: c++, string

```
string s;
s += '\0';
s += '\t';
if (s == "\0\t")
    cout << "Yahoo";
```

I can't get "yahoo".

And does it mean that if I want to check string like this, I have to code like this?

```
if (s[0] == '\0' && s[1] == '\t')
    cout << "Yahoo";
```

Comment: Because a literal string can't contain `\0`. That's taken as the terminator.

Comment: @EJP it can contain `\0` , the problem is when using the constructor `std::string(char const *)`.    For example, `cout << "ab\0c"[3]` <-- `c`

Comment: If you want to check "strings" like that you need to use a `vector<char>` as by definition in C++ strings are zero-terminated.

Comment: @RedX: String _literals_. And no, you don't need `vector<char>` at all. Just pass the exact length instead of relying on the default ctor converting: `if (s==std::string("\0\t", 2))`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using the operator which compares a `std::string` with a `const char*`. In that function, the `const char*` is assumed to be pointing to a null-terminated (i.e. `'\0'`) c-string.  Since the `'\t'` comes after the terminator, the function does not consider it as part of the string, and in fact, would have no good way of even being able to figure out that it was there.

You could do this:

```
if (s == std::string("\0\t",2))
```

That will construct a `std::string` with the full string literal (minus the terminating `'\0'` that the compiler adds), and will compare your string with that.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Benjamins answer. C++14 introduces string literals. It enables you to specify that a char sequence (like "a\0bc") should be treated as a string. You just have to you the s-suffix.

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

if (s == "\0\t"s)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is cool, but I can't use this feature in my project for the constraint of compiler.